# Passing a JavaScript variable to a razor function in jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a function `Convert(string name)` defined in razor c#.

Next, I have a jquery data table that consists of a hyperlink on the first row. The issue is that I need to invoke this `C#` function within the jquery datatable.

```
"render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return '<a href="/Home/Detail?search=' + row.Id + '">'
```

I want to invoke this C# `Convert(string name)` function in the jquery datatable like follows:

```
 "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return '<a href="/Home/Detail?search=' + @Check(row.Id) + '">
```

But it's not working as expected. Could someone please help?

Comment: You can't mix server-side and client-side code like that. Can you provide `Convert(string name)`/`Check` content? If you just want to convert a string to another type, use default JS conversion functions.

Comment: Its a long c# code that performs an ecryption. Any alternative for this to encrypt the `row.Id` ?

Comment: Your c# razor code is executed on the server and is unavailable on the client. You'll need to expose your function via a web API method and invoke it on the client. There are ways to asynchronously perform HTTP requests prior to rendering your datatable column -- search for "ajax render datatable" for more information.

Comment: I just read your message -- why are you encrypting the row ID? Unless you mean URL encoding since you're passing it as a search parameter. Search for URL encoding in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes. I am encoding the row.Id since I am passing it through the URL. The encryption is performed via a C# code. But I am unable to invoke the c# code within the jQuery datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly you can't pass client-side variable directly to server-side method like this:

```
"render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<a href="/Home/Detail?search=' + @Check(row.Id) + '">'
          }
```

The reason behind it is because all server side codes are executed immediately after the page is loaded and only client-side scripts remain afterwards. You need to use either `JsonResult` or Web API method and create a JS function to make AJAX callback with `jQuery.ajax()` (either using `GET` or `POST` method depending on your choice) and returns conversion result.

Here are examples for both ways:

**1) Using AJAX callback with `JsonResult`**

**JS**

```
function check(rowId) {
    var rid = { name: rowId };
    $.post('@Url.Action("Convert", "ControllerName")', rid).done(function (result) {
        // do something
        return result;
    }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, err) {
        // error handling
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Convert(string name)
{
    // do something

    return Json(result);
}
```

**2) Using AJAX callback with Web API (i.e. `ApiController`)**

**JS**

```
function check(rowId) {
    var rid = { name: rowId };
    $.post('api/Convert', rid).done(function (result) {
        // do something
        return result;
    }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, err) {
        // error handling
    });
}
```

**Web API Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Convert(string name) 
{
    // do something

    return new JsonResult<string>(result);
}
```

Both methods have same implementation in `render` part, just call `check` function and pass `row.Id` as argument:

**DataTable**

```
"render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<a href="/Home/Detail?search=' + check(row.Id) + '">';
          }
```

**Note:** The JS-based `check` function above should declared outside `DataTable` definition.

Answer (score 0):

If  that method can be easily implemented on javascript go with javascript else you need to create WebMethod on controller side in order to call C# method from javascript like this

```
[WebMethod]                                 
public static void Convert(string name)
{
//Your Logic
 }
```

Then call inside script like this

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'Yourcontrollername/Convert',
     data: {name="somename"},
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (msg) {
        //do something with result
     },
     error: function (e) {
        alert("Something Wrong.");
     }
 });
```